# Rotate wont work after translate

Tags: android, rotation, translate-animation

I have programatically translated an image. Later, in my code, I attempt to rotate the image about its own center. But the rotate is rotating the image around its original placement before it was translated. I have commented out the translate portion of code and everything works fine, the image rotates around its on center. But when I translate it first, the rotate doesnt take the new position into account. What do I need to do?

```
View v;
animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(),R.anim.slide_in_up);
v.setTranslationY(#);
v.startAnimation(anim);
```

xml below:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <rotate
  android:fromDegrees="-360.0"
  android:toDegrees="0.0"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to rotate the image first and then translate it. i was doing it the other way which is why it was not rotating about the center.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to add [`android:fillAfter="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3afillAfter) or the equivalent from code [`setFillAfter(boolean fillAfter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29) to make the transformation persistent after finishing the translation.

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed
>   will persist when it is finished. Defaults to false if not set.

// Edit: I initially didn't read you were using the API Level 11+ setTranslationY method.

> Sets the vertical location of this view relative to its top position.
>   This effectively positions the object post-layout, in addition to
>   wherever the object's layout placed it.

My guess is that the post-layout positioning does not influence all dependencies for the Animation, e.g. it does not do the equivalent of 'fillAfter', hence your result is not whay you expect. A not so pretty workaround might be to drop the setTranslationY method and accomplish the translation with a TranslationAnimation. By setting the duration to zero, you can mimmick an 'instant' translation. I've successfully done animated rotations after translations myself, so using this approach you should be able to get the result your looking for...

Comment: thanks but no. at the end of the animation, the view is in the correct place. but its rotating around the original coordinates instead of the new location resulting from  setTranslateY(). the setTranslateY()  also works, it goes to the right place and persists when the method is called

Comment: Sorry, I initially misunderstood a part of your issue. I updated my answer with a suggestion that might be worth looking into in case you can't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behaviour of the 9 patch algorithm. I found a way to do this with canvas.
The algorithm works is such a way that the translation occurs relative to the rotation axis.
The steps to achieving this is to create a canvas custom view in Android Studio.
You need to use the canvas to rotate first, then set the bounds of the drawable which will straighten the canvas and then you can translate normally.
I have an open source library that demonstrates this.
You can find the library here: https://bitbucket.org/warwick/hacergestov3
The Youtube demo here: https://youtu.be/0CoX5WUL6_8
Or download the library demo app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.WarwickWestonWright.HacerGestoV3Demo
Alternatively you can use OpenGL ES instead.